# How to use XML as template for Java to read HTML?

Tags: java, html, xml, templates

I have a Java application that will parse html pages and extract data from them. Currently, I have a class that acts as template or instructions on how to read a specific web page. The application will need to read from several different sites that will be formatted differently. Rather than creating a new template class for each type of format, I'd like to be able to read an accompanying XML file (or another document) that will provide the instructions as to which data and where to extract.

I've attempted to search the internet on how to do this, but I'm guessing I'm not asking the right question or using the right keywords.

The solution doesn't have to use XML as the template, but it was my first thought.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Extractor` uses `ExtractionInstructions` to extract the data of interest from a single source. You can later retrieve the extracted data from the extractor.

In this high-level design

- Source: Each page that you want to extract the same data from
- Extractor: 1 instance for each extraction run on a single source
- ExtractionInstructions: A set of instructions unambiguously describing a way to extract data from a single source.

  - You can specify the instructions unambiguously by

    - tag id and/or
    - Using CSS 3 selectors and/or
    - xpath etc.
  - You can use a combination of all the above by chaining them together (chain of responsibility pattern) to have more percentage of success. Idea is if the data is not found using 1 type of extraction, then you can try with other options until you either find the data or you ran out of the instructions).

I suggest using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) as the base library to build these abstractions.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you. This is the sort of direction I think I'm looking for. Your high-level design gives me some ideas on how to design and implement something like this. I'm already using Jsoup to parse the html, so hooking up an extractor shouldn't pose too much of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a template in xml you could keep [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) expressions that map to your desired data for each site you are reading.  Then as the pages you are scraping change you can just update the xpath expressions for that site.

Comment: That sounds like what I'm looking for. Thank you, I've never used xpath, but I will take a look.

Comment: The only problem is when your HTML is not a well-formed XML, in the case you can't use XPath

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh has a point there, you'd have to make sure that the html is tidied and well formed before you can use xpath.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh - Yes you can. Use a good HTML parser like [the Validator.nu HTML parser](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/) and no matter how malformed the markup, it will build a DOM that can be used with any standard XML tool chain, including XPath.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually done something like this before but it was rather complicated. Basically I made a plugin system (disgustingly like Maven) that you could parameterize extraction plugins.

You can do this using Spring Bean XML as your DSL.

```
<bean id="strategy1"  class="absolute.class.name">
</bean>

<bean id="extractorExecutor" class="class.to.extractorExecutor">
   <property name="strategies">
    <list>
        <item ref="strategy1" />
        <item ref="strategy2" />
     </list>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Your extractor basically loops through bunch of beans that implement an interface like:

```
public interface ExtractStrategy {
    /**
     * null means skip this extractor and go to the next one.
     */
    public Extracted extract(String data);
}
```

In your extractor you do:

```
for (ExtractorStrategy e : strategies) {
    Extracted ex = e.extract(data);
    if (ex != null) break;
}
```

Spring calls this the resolver chain pattern, some people call it the strategy pattern.

Then you can make an XPath extractor like @digitaljoel said and/or a Regex Extractor... etc.
You put the strategies in the order you would like them to run.

I have used this pattern all the time when [data-mining](/questions/tagged/data-mining) where you need heuristics. For extracting nasty HTML (mentioned in your comments from others) I recommend [**Jericho**](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) or [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) (in which case you make a Jericho strategy and just add to the chain).